# Best way to handle column that doesn't conform to one particular type

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a `Settings` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Settings` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  `Default` varchar(30) NOT NULL, <<<<<<<
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The `Default` value may however be integers, booleans, text, enums etc. etc.
I have set it to varchar right now, and when retrieving the setting, I will know what setting it is, e.g Send me daily emails - True/False, and do a case at the application level given that I know the type the value should be for that particular setting.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: In contrast to my answer to your [other question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56635), where I suggested a model that looks like EAV, in this case... danger, your long-term interests may not be served by this approach.  Columns of the appropriate types are likely better.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is this what you mean http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/163607/59685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are proposing is workable but informal.  A more formal approach can be found in my answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50567/configuration-table/50587#50587).

The basic pattern is called a **Property Bag**.

Comment: Very interesting, are there any books written on this sort of thing (patterns such as Property Bags and so on)

Comment: @lee - There are lots of good books - too many to be on topic for StackExchange.  Try Googling around for technical books that include the word "Cookbook" in the title.  That's a good indication that it's a collection of patterns/applications/best practices.